# Can someone tell me what is the problem in my code

Tags: java, arrays

**Class `pair`**

```java
public static class pair {
    int x;
    int y;

    public void pair(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

**`main` function**

What I want to do is to create an array of objects of class `pair` and take input in the array of objects

```java
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    pair[] p = new pair[2];

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        p[i].x = sc.nextInt(); // here I get the error is "Cannot assign field "x" because "p[i]" is null" 
        p[i].y = sc.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your indentation on your `class pair` fragment, while not wrong, is making it difficult to read. Should the first line, `public static class pair{` , be un-indented one level?

Comment: Also please rename your class to `Pair` with a capital `P`, to follow the Java code conventions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    pair[] p;

    int x, y;

    p = new pair[2];

    for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
        x = sc.nextInt();
        y = sc.nextInt();
        p[i] = new pair(x,y); 
    // Assign Object Instead of assigning to class members
    }
    
    for (int j = 0; j < p.length; j++) {
        System.out.println(p[j].x + " "+ p[j].y);
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- `pair(int x,int y)` is a constructor, it should not have a return type. So, it should be `public pair(int x, int y)`
- `pair[] p = new pair[2];` is creating an array of references to `pair`. So, you will need to create new objects using `p[i] = new pair(sc.nextInt(),sc.nextInt());`
- You have to close the scanner. So, at the end of the code: `sc.close()`. You have to do it even if the code is working.

Answer (score 1):

When you're creating an array of `pair` (`pair[] p = new pair[2]`), the elements of this array are `null`, they are not assigned to the `new pair` objects, since `pair` is not a primitive but a class.

```
        pair[] p = new pair[2];

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            p[i] = new pair(); // set p[i] to a new object
            p[i].x = sc.nextInt(); // now it will work
            p[i].y = sc.nextInt();
        }
```